# How to post data from jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datatable

I need to bind jquery dataTable using handler and I am sending parameters to that handler which is through  object log given below.On button click I am calling the a function in which I have written the below code. On clicking on the button I need to have the datatable.But the problem is that I am unable to bind the jquery datatable. Please help.
Is there anyway to pass log as parameter to jquery datatable call and capture that in handler?

```
var log = { LogType: logType, InstanceID: instanceId, StartDateTime: StartDateTime, EndDateTime: EndDateTime, UserId: UserId, SearchKey: SearchValue, ProjectID: projectId, ClassID: ClassId, MethodID: MethodId, UserName: UserName, FilePath: FilePath };

                $.ajax({
                    url: "LogManager.ashx",
                    dataType: "json",
                    responseType: "json",
                    data: { searchlog: JSON.stringify(log) },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#tblLogTable').DataTable({
                            "data": data,
                            "columns": [
                                { 'data': "stProjectName" },
                                { 'data': "stMethodName" },
                                { 'data': "stUserName" },
                                { 'data': "stFilePath" },
                                { 'data': "stClassName" },
                                { 'data': "inUserId" },
                                { 'data': "dtCreationTime" },
                                { 'data': "stLog" },
                                { 'data': "stInstance" },
                            ],
                            "language": {
                                "emptyTable": "There are no records at present.",
                            "zeroRecords": "There were no matching records found."
                        },
                            processing: true,
                            serverSide: false,
                            ordering: true,
                            paging: true,
                            searching: true
                            });


                        },


                    error: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: "unable to" isn't an error message or problem statement. What's going wrong? What happened / didn't happen which was unexpected? Have you got any errors or warnings in your console? What other debugging have you done to narrow down the problem?

Comment: I am noticing ashx, is it a typo of aspx?

Comment: @C.Geek-No ashx stands for handler

Comment: Why is Datatable inside the success? It should be the other way around...

Comment: This is not a clear to me.. you are using .ashx to pass the data from ajax? @SristiAnnu

Answer (score 0):

It should be the other way around e.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#mytable').DataTable({
      processing: true,
      serverSide: true,
      ajax: {
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/DataTables.aspx/Data",
        data: function (d) {
          return JSON.stringify({ parameters: d });
        }
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
```